# simple UISearchBar and UITextView app

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

I'd like to see a tutorial which shows a UISearchBar as well as a UITextView where you type something in the UISearchBar and it appears in the UITextView as you type it.

I've pulled my hair out over this and am now redesigning my app with a text field and button because I can't get my head around UISearchBarDelegate and how it integrates with UISearchBar. Apple has an official example, except that it's very complicated. My post detailing my frustrations can be found here: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/ip...html#post12603

If anyone could do this screencast, I would highly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the UISearchBar delegate method: -(void)searchBar :(UISearchBar*)theSearchBar textDidChange :(NSString*)searchText

then just use myTextView.text = searchBar.text whenever that method gets called.

Tariq